# How to update PhantomJS in Karma or set correct version to start?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, phantomjs, karma-runner

I installed

```
"phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.12"
```

but when i start test by Grunt i still see in console INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1].

Also I have installed plugin:

```
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.1",
"karma": "1.1.2",
```

If anyone knows where it can be updated ? or set correct version to start ?

Comment: Set Karma to debug mode logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG and read the logs. Should at least be a good start.

Comment: Can you check what is installed globally? One more query, how did you install it? exact statement please..